# how to display number in textview(activity2) from edittext(activity1) ? Say example phone number

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, textview

**Activity 1:**

public class Start extends ActionBarActivity {

```
EditText MobileNo;
EditText Name;
Button Next;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

  Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);   

    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MobileNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MobileNumber);
        int Data = Integer.parseInt(MobileNo.getText().toString());

        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        String Data1 = Name.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(Start.this,GetStarted.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("MobileNo",  Data);
        extras.putString("Name",  Data1);

        i.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    });
}
```

**Activity 2:**

TextView MobileNo1;
    TextView Name1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_getstarted);


    int myNo = 0;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        myNo = extras.getInt("MobileNo");
    }

   MobileNo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   MobileNo1.setText(Integer.toString(myNo));

   String myName = null;
    Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras1!=null)
    {
        myName = extras1.getString("Name");
    }

   Name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   Name1.setText(myName);

    }
```

So, Its getting an error in here (MobileNo1.setText(Integer.toString(myNo));) Please help through exceptions if any!! Also Please help with the number format exception, Iam not able to give input more than 9 digits.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: try `MobileNo1.setText(String.valueOf(myNo));`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write:

```
MobileNo1.setText("" + myNo);
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot!! It worked....Keep in touch I may ask you many question until I finish my project.  Thank youuuu!! :-)

Comment: Glad it worked ! And welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) some documents to get familiar with how things work here and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that worked for you.

Comment: I'd suggest using String.valueOf(myNo) instead of "" + myNo

Comment: @ChadiAbouSleiman Iam getting number format exception while giving input, Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

in EditText activity2:

```
String enteredText = editText.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("value" , enteredText);
startActivity(intent);
```

in TextView activity1:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String enteredText = intent.getStringExtra("value", "0");
textView.setText(enteredText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your myNo in string by using `myNo.toString());`